# Why not "A" big bang

Tags: big-bang

What has led us to believe that there was "1" big bang and not multiple?

Comment: How many universes are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the evidence supporting 1 singular Big Bang?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32598/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse